# MySQL ON UPDATE/ON DELETE CASCADE not CASCADEing

Tags: mysql, relational-database, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

When I edit UID on the signup table, the parentid column on the clients table is supposed to change. It's not doing that. Any suggestions?

**Clients**

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
    `id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `lname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `phone` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `parentid` INT(255) NOT NULL,
    `hphone` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `postal` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `city` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `province` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `country` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `sms` INT(1) NOT NULL,
    `semail` INT(1) NOT NULL,
    `gender` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `bday` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `bmonth` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `parentid` (`parentid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_clients_signup` FOREIGN KEY (`parentid`) REFERENCES `signup` (`UID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
AUTO_INCREMENT=31751
```

**Signup**

```
CREATE TABLE `signup` (
    `UID` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `hash` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `email` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `fname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `lname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `address` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `city` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `province` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `zip` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `country` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `company` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `addtime` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `logintime` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `user_ip` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `pwd` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `credits` INT(255) NOT NULL,
    `plan` INT(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `reset` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `expires` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `afid` INT(255) NOT NULL,
    `industryid` INT(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`UID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `email` (`email`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `username` (`username`),
    INDEX `industryid` (`industryid`),
    INDEX `afid` (`afid`),
    INDEX `plan` (`plan`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_signup_affiliates` FOREIGN KEY (`afid`) REFERENCES `affiliates` (`afid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_signup_plans` FOREIGN KEY (`plan`) REFERENCES `plans` (`pid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
AUTO_INCREMENT=27
```

Comment: _When I edit UID on signup id on clients is supposed to change_ According to your `CREATE TABLE` statement, `Clients.id` shouldn't change, rather `Clients.parentid` should.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (\`parentid\`) REFERENCES \`signup\` (\`UID\`)`   Make sure you're looking at the right column for changes.

Comment: Sorry I meant parentid should change. UID is the primary key of signup and the part that needs to change in clients is parentid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not changing because you can't possibly change the UID on the signup table since it's the **primary key, and is auto incremented**

Comment: not really what I'm looking for. In any case it's started working by itself for some reason.